# Unable to click button in dynamically created table cell

Tags: javascript, button, hover

I am creating a table dynamically in which there are buttons at the end of each row.

The problem is, I can't make the hover effect work. If I set the eventlistener on the button as well, only the eventlistener set on the div shoots. Of course, if I set the eventlistener only on the button, nothing happens.

```
else if (j == 5) {
    //if it's the 5th column in the table, create a button in each row.
    td.className = 'editrow';

    var edit_btn = document.createElement('button');
    edit_btn.innerText = "Edit";
    edit_btn.className = 'edit_word';

    td.appendChild(edit_btn);

    td.addEventListener("click", function() {
        //This shoots: when I click on the table cell (so on the button or outside it)
        //I cannot set edit_btn.addEventListener, it doesn't do anything
        console.log("clicked");
    });

}
```

I believe the button is covered (or behind) the td and that is why the hover doesn't work.

This image may help it imagine. The yellow background color is a hover effect shot on hovering above the td (let it be the td or the button inside it). The design of the button never changes and I double checked it should be and yes, css is correct.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted works fine. Perhaps there's something else amiss, like CSS pointer-event overrides or HTML structure problems. What happens if you right-click the button and choose "Inspect Element", which element does it highlight?

https://jsfiddle.net/amsv/tk3jbcms/

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="td"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
var td = document.getElementById("td");
var clicked = 0;

td.className = 'editrow';

var edit_btn = document.createElement('button');
edit_btn.innerText = "Edit";
edit_btn.className = 'edit_word';

td.appendChild(edit_btn);

edit_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Logging number of times clicked..
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.innerHTML = "Clicked: " + clicked++ + " times."
});
```

Comment: Do you have a listener on the TD already that perhaps makes use of the preventDefault and/or stopPropagation methods? Or button CSS that prevents pointer-events.

Comment: Might also want to compare z-indexes, if you've modified those. Add "z-index: 9999" to the button in the browser developer console and see if it has any effect.

Comment: Finally! It was your css idea that help me find this little monster: ```pointer-events: none;``` I have no idea how it got there.

Answer (score 0):

you may try the following script in head section of page :

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.className== 'edit_word'){
        console.log("clicked")
     }
 });
</script>
```

and remove the  td.addEventListener method from your code

or using jQuery

````
<script>
$(function(){ 

   $(document).on('click','.edit_word',function(){ 

       console.log("clicked"); 

    });

 });
</script>```
````

Comment: Nothing is shown in the console.. This must be something else than this block of the code

Comment: This won't work, as the click events is caught by the TD :)

Comment: ok do you have jQuery, if you use jquery then you may write like this :
 


 
$(function(){

$(document).on('click','.edit_word',function(){ 

        console.log("clicked");

     });

 });